# CakePhp sending response as Json and displaying it

Tags: cakephp, jquery, cakephp-2.1

i am trying to auto complete department using jquery autocomplete library. 
 ajax call is as follows

```
     $( "#auto_complete" ).autocomplete({
        source: function( request, response ) {
            $.ajax({
                url:  "/employees/getDepartment"
                dataType: "jsonp",
                //dataType: "text/html",
                data: {
                    featureClass: "P",
                    style: "full",
                    maxRows: 12,
                    name_startsWith: request.term
                },
                success: function( data ) {
                    alert("success--");
                    response( $.map( data.geonames, function( item ) {
                        return {
                            label: item.name,
                            value: item.id
                        }
                    }));
                }
            });
        },
        minLength: 2,
        select: function( event, ui ) {
            log( ui.item ?
                "Selected: " + ui.item.label :
                "Nothing selected, input was " + this.value);
        },
        open: function() {
            $( this ).removeClass( "ui-corner-all" ).addClass( "ui-corner-top" );
        },
        close: function() {
            $( this ).removeClass( "ui-corner-top" ).addClass( "ui-corner-all" );
        }
    });
```

my controller has a action  called getDepartment is as follows:

```
     public function getDepartment() {
        $this->log($this->params->query['name_startsWith'] , 'debug');
        $str = $this->params->query['name_startsWith'];
        $this->log($str, 'debug');
        $name='Departmet';
        $this->layout = 'ajax';
        $departments = $this->Employee->Department->find('all', array( 'recursive' => -1,
            'conditions'=>array('Department.name LIKE'=>$str.'%'),
            'fields'=>array('name', 'id')));
        $this->set('departments',$departments);
}
```

here i need to send the $departments as Json .

1. how to send the response as JSON
2. why controller is not reaching autocomplete success function (where i have put an alert)

when i run i get response (using fireBug) as

```
      [{"Department":{"name":"Testing","id":"1"}},{"Department":{"name":"Testing","id":"3"}},{"Department":{"name":"Testing2","id":"6"}},{"Department":{"name":"testing","id":"7"}},{"Department":{"name":"test","id":"8"}}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Your response is valid JSON and so your `dataType` must be too.

```
dataType: "json"
```